# How do I add an array as an Object Property to a class declared within a PHP extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension, php-internals

I want my PHP extension to declare a class equivalent to the following PHP:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $MyMemberArray;

    __construct()
    {
        $this->MyMemberArray = array();
    }
}
```

I'm following the examples in "[Advanced PHP Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Advanced-PHP-Programming-Developers-Library/dp/0672325616)" and "[Extending and Embedding PHP](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Extending-Embedding-PHP-Sara-Golemon/dp/067232704X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1247160557&sr=1-1)" and I'm able to declare a class that has integer properties in `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION`.

However, when I use the same approach to declare an array property in `PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION`, I get the following error message at runtime:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Internal zval's can't be arrays, objects or resources in Unknown on line 0
```

There's an example on page 557 of Advanced PHP Programming of how to declare a constructor which creates an array property, but the example code doesn't compile (the second "object" seems to be redundant).

I fixed the bug and adapted it to my code:

```
PHP_METHOD(MyClass, __construct)
{
    zval *myarray;
    zval *pThis;

    pThis = getThis();

    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(myarray);

    array_init(myarray);
    zend_declare_property(Z_OBJCE_P(pThis), "MyMemberArray", sizeof("MyMemberArray"), myarray, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC TSRMLS_DC);
}
```

And this compiles, but it gives the same runtime error on construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to use `add_property_zval_ex()` in the constructor, rather than `zend_declare_property()`.

The following works as intended:

```
PHP_METHOD(MyClass, __construct)
{
    zval *myarray;
    zval *pThis;

    pThis = getThis();

    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(myarray);

    array_init(myarray);
    add_property_zval_ex(pThis, "MyMemberArray", sizeof("MyMemberArray"), myarray);
}
```

Comment: but do you know WHY this is the answer? what is the reasoning?

Comment: The reasoning has to do with how a zval is created. It is a long winded explaination, trust me.