# how do you create a private property as an array in a class within php ext

Tags: c, php-extension

I'm still new to writing extensions. I'm trying to get this to be the outcome:

```
class FooClass {
    private $elements = array();
}
```

I'm getting an error when instantiating FooClass:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property ArrayClass::$elements

I know exactly why that's happening I just don't know the correct way of creating a class definition as an array. This is what I have so far, I'm sure it's trivial:

```
static zend_class_entry *foo_class_ptr;

void create_class_properties(TSRMLS_D) {
     zend_declare_property_null(foo_class_ptr, "elements", strlen("elements"), ZEND_ACC_PRIVATE);
}

ZEND_METHOD(foo_class, __construct) { 
    zval *this = getThis();
    zval *elements;

    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(elements);
    array_init(elements);

    add_property_zval_ex(this, "elements", sizeof("elements"), elements);
}

static zend_function_entry foo_class_methods_def[] = { 
    PHP_ME(foo_class, __construct, NULL, ZEND_ACC_PUBLIC)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

void create_class_def(TSRMLS_D) {
    zend_class_entry ce;
    INIT_CLASS_ENTRY(ce, "FooClass", foo_class_methods_def);

    foo_class_ptr = zend_register_internal_class(&ce);
}
```

create_class_def get's called from PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(). There's a similiar question here: [How do I add an array as an Object Property to a class declared within a PHP extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105360/how-do-i-add-an-array-as-an-object-property-to-a-class-declared-within-a-php-ext) but it does not address private/protected access.

thx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to use `zend_update_property`:

`void zend_update_property(zend_class_entry *scope, zval *object, const char *name, int name_length, zval *value TSRMLS_DC);`

`name_length` is excluding the terminator.